# Get All Elements in HTML body

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, document-body

I am trying to write a Javascript function to get all the elements in a HTML body.
I tried something like:

```
function getAllElements(){
        let el = document.body.childNodes;
        for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
        {
            if(el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyparentdiv" || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeydiv"
            || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyspan1" || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyspan2")
            {
                el[i].classList.add("opacityformonkey");
            }
        }
}
```

And In the CSS I have

```
.opacity-for-monkey{
    animation-name: burnImage;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes burnImage {
    from {
        opacity: 1
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.3
    }
}
```

Long story short I want to set the opacity to 0.3 for all the elements except the ones mentioned in the if condition.

But it's giving me an error:

```
el[i].getAttribute is not a function.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a part of the html part

Comment: Your childNodes will contain text elements as well. They won't have an id. So you get that error. https://nimb.ws/VUB5fa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.body.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns all types of nodes including text nodes that don't have attributes. You should use [`document.body.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead.

Also, your JavaScript code adds the class `opacityformonkey` (no hyphens), but in CSS you have `opacity-for-monkey` (with hyphens).

Comment: That worked just fine.
And thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

All the child nodes might not be an element. You will have to check for Text Node as well and exclude them. Here is the modified version of your code:

```
function getAllElements(){
    let el = document.body.childNodes;
    for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++){
        if (el[i].nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE){
            if(el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyparentdiv" || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeydiv"
            || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyspan1" || el[i].getAttribute("id") != "monkeyspan2")
            {
                el[i].classList.add("opacityformonkey");
            }
        }
    }
}
```